# PHP local server - double errors - bug or not?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm having a weird problem with error output on PHP's built-in server, and it really looks like a bug, but I'm not 100% sure.

Example script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
ini_set('log_errors', '1');
ini_set('ignore_repeated_errors', true);

trigger_error('my notice', E_USER_NOTICE);
trigger_error('my warning', E_USER_WARNING);
```

If you execute this code in the console (`php example.php`), you get the following, expected, output:

```
PHP Notice:  my notice in C:\php\example.php on line 7
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\php\example.php:0
PHP   2. trigger_error('my notice', 1024) C:\php\example.php:7
PHP Warning:  my warning in C:\php\example.php on line 8
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\php\example.php:0
PHP   2. trigger_error('my warning', 512) C:\php\example.php:8
```

However, if you run this script as a webpage (`php -S localhost:9000 example.php`), and open the URL, you get the following output in the console:

```
PHP 7.1.10 Development Server started at Tue Oct 10 19:46:05 2017
Listening on http://localhost:9000
Document root is C:\php
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:06 2017] PHP Notice:  my notice in C:\php\example.php on line 7
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:06 2017] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:06 2017] PHP   1. {main}() C:\php\example.php:0
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:06 2017] PHP   2. trigger_error('my notice', 1024) C:\php\example.php:7
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:06 2017] PHP Warning:  my warning in C:\php\example.php on line 8
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:06 2017] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:06 2017] PHP   1. {main}() C:\php\example.php:0
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:06 2017] PHP   2. trigger_error('my warning', 512) C:\php\example.php:8
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:07 2017] PHP Notice:  my notice in C:\php\example.php on line 7
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:07 2017] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:07 2017] PHP   1. {main}() C:\php\example.php:0
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:07 2017] PHP   2. trigger_error('my notice', 1024) C:\php\example.php:7
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:07 2017] PHP Warning:  my warning in C:\php\example.php on line 8
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:07 2017] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:07 2017] PHP   1. {main}() C:\php\example.php:0
[Tue Oct 10 19:46:07 2017] PHP   2. trigger_error('my warning', 512) C:\php\example.php:8
```

The weirdest thing is that if you add `trigger_error('my error', E_USER_ERROR);` at the bottom of the example script, the double output is fixed.

What causes this? Is it a bug or some weirdness with the INI configs?

Comment: Before everything else make sure there is only one HTTP request. The output you posted is normal for two requests.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Dunno if this narrows it down, but I wasn't able to replicate this on my Linux box.

Comment: Agree with the two requests idea - the fact the timestamps don't overlap adds to this. Check network tools in the browser/etc. Have you perhaps got a request for a favicon in there?

Comment: Yeah, just checked network and it requests favicon and it goes to this file as well... What the hell?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the answer is in the question. You launched the internal web server with a script and it uses the script as a router. This means it invokes that script for every request it receives. The browser, of course, requires `favicon.ico` and the rest you already figured out.

Launch the PHP's internal web server without a router, use the `-t` command line option to tell it where to find the files to server (the root directory of the website):

```
php -S localhost:9000 C:\php
```

Comment: Who even writes PHP code without a router these days, cmon man. That style is so old, outdated and causes unnecessary problems.

I'll vote it up only because it would work IF I wrote code like that, but I don't, so can't accept it.

Comment: Who writes a site without a `favicon.ico` these days, cmon man ;-)

Comment: How about APIs?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - no real fix available, only workarounds.

Long version:

Apparently this is caused by the browser **always** requesting a favicon, and there is literally no way to tell it to stop, no headers or anything.

The only thing you can do is either `1`) actually implement a favicon.ico for your API, or `2`) put a link in your page's `<head>` block, like so:

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
</head>
```

The second option obviously won't work for JSON APIs and such, so if you ever open a route that responds with anything other than HTML in your browser (e.g. an API request from your one-page app to backend), or even access any static content directly (e.g. `http://localhost:9000/css/reset.css`, which apparently also requests a favicon if one hasn't been cached yet) - only option 1 is "good" for that.